# There has been a 500 error on the Your Platform Name Here servers - Django/Openedx

Tags: django, bitnami, openedx

Mistakenly I deleted **'example.com'** which was default site using Django administration web interface and there is no other site available. Now while restarting the server, it ended up with

> There has been a 500 error on the Your Platform Name Here servers

On google i got the solution "updating the SITE_ID property in the `/opt/bitnami/apps/edx/edx-platform/lms/envs/common.py file`" but it can only work if i have any site configure in Mysql database.

In which table do I have to add data for configuring my site?

Comment: Check the table, "django_site"

Comment: @Isanka Wijerathne I checked for the table 'django_site' under bitnami_edxapp . But on doing desc django_site , I didn't findd the schema of the table. So can you please help me out with the schema of the table?